# Prove that if p divides xy then p divides x or p divides y

Tags: prime-numbers, alternative-proof

I am given that the following proposition is true. (Proved in class)

"Suppose that $x$, $y\in \Bbb Z$, not both zero. Then there exists $m$, $n\in\Bbb Z$ such that $$mx + ny = d$$ where $d$ is the greatest common factor of $x$ and $y$.  Moreover, if $ax + by = f$ for some $a$, $b$, $f\in\Bbb Z$ then $d | f$."

Using the statement above, prove that if $p$ is prime and $p|xy$ then $p|x$ or $p|y$. (hint: if $p$ does not divide $x$, then $p$ and $x$ are relatively prime)(We just learned the definition of  relatively prime, so that is probably why that hint is there.)

I just don't get why I need to use the statement above.  The way I see it, if $p|xy$ then there are two possible cases:

1. $p|x$
2. $p$ does not divide $x$

And obviously, if $p|x$ then the original statement is true, and if $p$ does not divide $x$ then I just need to prove that $p|y$ in that case which I could do.  That seems simpler than any other way, am I wrong?  Working with prime numbers always throws me.  I don't get why it matters if $p$ is prime, so if someone wants to explain that, it would be a nice addition.

Comment: To see why it matters that $p$ is prime, note that $6\mid 3\cdot4$, but $6\nmid3$ and $6\nmid4$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** $gcd(p,x)$ is a divisor of $p$. Therefore it is either $p$ or $1$.

If the gcd is $p$ it means $p|x$ and you already treated that case.

Otherwise, by the lemma
$$mp+nx=1$$
Multiply this by $y$, and use that $p|xy$.

**P.S.** The key to the proof is that $p$ is prime, otherwise the gcd could be something else but 1 or p. And it was already shown by examples that in that case the statement is not true.

Comment: Ok, so I get 

$$m(py) + n(xy) = y$$

And I am not quite sure what to do.  We now know that $y$ is the gcd of $py$ and $xy$, but that doesn't seem that helpful.  So I'm not quite sure what to do next.

Comment: @Sam Two of those terms are divisible by $p$ ;)

Comment: Wait, so since $p|(mpy)$ and $p|(nxy)$, it must be true that $p|y$? Is that statement true?

Comment: @Sam Yup. If $p$ divides 2 numbers it divides their sum

Answer (score 0):

If $p$ is not prime, the following thing is posssible:

> $p|xy$, however $p$ does not divide $x$ and $y$.

For example, 8|2\times 4, however $8\not| 2 $ and $8\not| 4 $.